# java.net.ConnectException - Connection Refused Android Emulator

Tags: sockets, android-emulator, socketexception

I have an android emulator I'm running from eclipse and just trying to connect to a simple socket server I wrote in .NET (c#).

The server is running on the same machine on port 4505.  I am able to telnet (through PuTTy) to the server and it works just fine, but when I try to connect to the server with the android emulator I get a: java.net.ConnectException - localhost/127.0.0.1:4505 - Connection refused at org.apache.harmony.luni.net error.

I'm assuming this is because the emulator is on a different subnet or something?  If that were the case though I would think I would be getting a different error that would be caught in the UnknownHostException catch block...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got this figured out.  If I use the internal ip it works fine (192.168.1.%) address.

Sorry for the wasted space here but maybe someone else will be able to use this.

the 127.0.0.1 is for the device (emulator) itself.

Answer (score 43):

According to [Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) IP `10.0.2.2` should be used instead of `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'localhost' put your address (192.168.1.%)